# Leaflet popups with source's special characters

Tags: arcgis-server, leaflet, popup, esri-leaflet

I've got a map where I integrate spatial point data from an ArcGIS Server. Now I want a popup triggered via a click on the point. I know how everything works and the popup is displayed.

But I've got the problem that some of the source's columns names are using German special characters (ü,ä,ö).

That leads to a strange behaviour when displaying the popup; instead of the data it shows the column's name. So how could I change the code's column tag to get the right information?

The code is published under [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/2/).

Any help is welcome.

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an explanation of the cause of the problem can be found [here](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/401).

Because `L.Util.template` only supports a limited characterset, the recommended solution is to use a more robust templating solution like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), Lodash or Handlebars in situations like this.

Comment: Okay, I understand the problem. But how should I build it into my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/3/)? I added the lodashjs resources already in the JSFiddle.

Comment: I got it. Can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p08s16se/4/)